# Python run from .BAT does not return any results

Tags: python, anaconda

Python 3.7.3 / Win 10
BAT file launches and logs it's start and end times, included Python script does not run, yields no results.  Dates.txt does not get created or updated, and print statements are not rendered.  No errors are returned, and my CMD window holds on the PAUSE.

I have tried all the variations I could find on SO for launching PY from BAT, and no joy.  There doesn't seem to be that many options for calling a .PY from within a .BAT. I've tried running the BAT and just the Python call on their own, from regular and elevated(admin) command prompts, no change.

get_dates.bat:

```
    SET logfile="J:\My Drive\_Ongoing\Python\250ok_v20\batch.log"
    @echo Starting Script at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
    "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "J:\My 
    Drive\_Ongoing\Python\250ok_v20\get_dates.py"
    pause
    @echo Finished at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
```

get_dates.py:

```py
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    from datetime import datetime

    file = "J:/My Drive/_Ongoing/Python/250ok_v20/date.txt"
    def get_dates():
        today = date.today()
        d = today - relativedelta(months=1)
        date(d.year, d.month, 1)
        startdate = (date(today.year, today.month, 1) - 
relativedelta(months=1))
        enddate = (date(today.year, today.month, 1) - relativedelta(days=1))
        startdate = str(startdate)
        enddate = str(enddate)
        return(startdate, enddate)

    (startdate, enddate)= get_dates()

    with open(file, 'w') as the_file:
        the_file.write(startdate+'\n')
        the_file.write(enddate+'\n')

    print(startdate)
    print(enddate)
```

The PY script runs fine from Spyder, dates.txt file gets created with correct values.
If I run:

```
"J:\My Drive\_Ongoing\Python\250ok_v20\test.bat"
```

from the CMD, `batch.log` gets start/end lines added, but `dates.txt` does not get created/refreshed.

If I run:

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "J:\My Drive\_Ongoing\Python\250ok_v20\get_dates.py"
```

nothing seems to happen, no traces.
Is this something to do with Anaconda?
I had another version of Python installed previously, and I may not have removed it before installing `Spyder/Anaconda`, could this cause issues?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure 'pythonw.exe' is your python? Anaconda usually installs mine as just 'python.exe'. This would explain why spyder runs the script, but neither the batch file or your command work - it looks like the script works fine when it runs.

Comment: I've tried running: "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "J:\My Drive\_Ongoing\Python\250ok_v20\get_dates.py", it returns 'date is undefined'.  Which I thought was odd.  But this is why I thought it might be Anaconda related.  Thanks.

Comment: you need to import date from datetime! spyder might have done this automatically?

Comment: Yup, that did it.  Added: from datetime import date, and now running it with python.exe, dates.txt is getting filled up, and print statements are working as well.  Thank you very much for this.  I tried to add that previously, but in trying too many things I probably skipped over the working combo...  Do you want ot post this as an answer so I can upvote?  Or should I?  I don't have much standing, not even sure I can upvote...

Answer (score 0):

This is a twofold problem:

- First, the script seems to work in Spyder, but not anywhere else. It looks like "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"  may be a typo - typical installs are just 'python.exe'
- Second, you will need to import date from datetime.

Comment: Pythonw.exe is the interpreter Spyder uses to show code execution in it's console _I think_, not 100% about that.  But the file exists at the location and is a valid .exe.  I did import date from datetime, and that fixed my issue.  Thanks for your help!